# Cannot format LocaDateTime given Object as a Date

Tags: java

I want to format a `LocalDateTime` using the following code:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
return dateFormat.format(LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(10));
```

but I have the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
```

Comment: This could have been solved by examining the documentation that comes with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not format the `java.time` types using the legacy formatting type, `java.text.DateFormat`. Use `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` instead.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        System.out.println(formatter.format(LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(10)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
20200415203347
```

Note that the `java.time` API, released with Java-8 in March 2014, supplanted the [error-prone legacy date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html). Since then, using this modern date-time API has been strongly recommended. Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different methods of dealing with dates in Java. `DateFormat` is for the old, not-to-be-used `java.util.Date` package. Your `LocalDateTime` is from the much better `java.time` package, and needs to use a `DateTimeFormatter`:

```java
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
return format.format(LocalDateTime.now().plusMinutes(10));
```

Comment: it is worth noting that calling the `ofPattern` method requires API level 26 and higher.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to use DateTimeFormatter instead of DateFormatter as the object you are trying to format is LocalDateTime.